# Difference between differentiation notations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Please is there a difference between:

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $(1 + x^2)$ where $y = (1 + x^2)$

and

$\frac{d(1+x^2)}{dx}$

Aren't they both going to result in $2x$?

Just curious as to why in some calculations its written one way and in some, the other way.

Comment: I've never seen the first one. You may write "$\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $y = 1+x^2$".

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what i meant, are they the same and can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: They can be used interchangeably.Just a stylistic thing or for the rhythm of your writing. You can do either basically.

Comment: The first one can be written as $y'(1+x^2)$. The second one is just the derivative of $y=1+x^2$ w.r.t $x$. This is indeed equal to $2x$. But about the first one we cannot say anything further. My comment is referring to the expression $dy/dx (1+x^2)=y'(1+x^2)=y'y$

Comment: FYI - to anyone confused by callculus's comment (like I was) - the question was clarified after callculus commented.